# Python: How to expand column with list of values to multiple rows?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, explode, expand

Have got a *df* which looks like this:

```
Item    Match
a       bb,cc
b       dd,ee
```

want to expland the column 'Match' as below:

```
Item    Match
a       bb
a       cc
b       dd
b       ee
```

tried `df.explode('Match')` but didn't worked for me. Kindly share your ideas.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12680754/split-explode-pandas-dataframe-string-entry-to-separate-rows

Comment: Will check this out. Thank You

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this will solve your issue:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"Item": ["a", "b"], "Match": ["bb,cc", "dd,ee"]})
df["Match"] = df["Match"].str.split(",")
df.explode("Match")
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you.

Comment: If this solves your issue could you please validate the answer